# Как запустить свой скрипт Python3 на разных ОС?

Tags: python, python-3.x, компиляция, ос

**Условие:**

1. У пользователя может быть операционная система Windows, Linux, X.
2. У пользователя не обязательно установлен Python.
3. У программиста есть скрипт Python3 с необходимым функционалом для пользователя. Скрипт содержит сторонние модули (например Pillow). Программист работает в Linux.

**Задача:**
 - Сделать скрип исполняемым без необходимости отдельного скачивания модулей, Python и дополнительных настроек системы.

Comment: pyinstaller и сборка для каждой ОС

Comment: Если нету желания, чтобы ваш "exe" декомпилировали и брали исходники - то Nuitka. Nuitka переводит код на питоне в С++ и потом компилирует в машинный код. И размер исполняемого файла становится поменьше.

Comment: Чтобы без изменений запускалось у любого пользователя на любой системе - никак. Только делать отдельные пакеты для каждой системы.

Comment: Можно делать это с использованием import os создайте проверку на ос через if и задайте параметры

Comment: задача звучит бессмысленной, если её понимать в прямом смысле. скрипт никак не может запускаться без интерпретатора.

Comment: @xmikex, задача как раз смысл имеет, но с таким набором параметров не имеет решения)

Comment: А, ну разве что сделать сайт, с которым пользователь будет работать через браузер, тогда условие кроссплатформенности и работы без интерпретатора python как бы будет выполнено.

Comment: задача исполнить скрипт без интерпретатора скриптов?  как по мне смысла в такой задачи нет. может он имел ввиду сделать единый файл, который будет работать на всех платформах, но тут тоже проблема. минимум обвязка к архиву с необходимым для исполнения скрипта в виде bat/ps1 и sh нужна будет, а под macos вообще хз что считается универсальным скриптовым решением.

Comment: и то смысл сомнительный тащить в один файл рантайм под все три ОС.

Answer (score 1):

cx_freeze модуль. Он не только собирает приложение в exe, но и может несложно собрать приложение в файл msi для windows со разными возможностями: иконка, путь установки, все атрибуты присущие msi пакету. Этот модуль собирает образы и для Mac.
Этот модуль показал себя лояльным к сборке модулей проекта. Собирал их без ошибок. К примеру pyinstaller без танцев с бубном не смог собрать то же приложение, которое содержит собственные дополнительные модули в приложение, которое смогло работать на сторонней машине без питона.

Answer (score 1):

Заверните свой скрипт в *Docker* контейнер. 
Контейнер вы можете запускать на любой платформе и с его запуском справится любой пользователь. Внутри контейнера будет установлен *Python* со всеми необходимыми зависимостями для запуска скрипта.

Таким образом выполняются все вышеперечисленные требования, а именно:

1. У пользователя может быть установлена любая *ОС*.
2. У пользователя не должен быть установлен *Python*.
3. Все блага *Docker'а* для программиста.

Comment: Во-первых, Docker доступен только для Linux (в Windows и macOS он запускается через виртуальную машину). Во-вторых, совсем не факт что справится любой пользователь. В-третьих, Docker подразумевает максимальную изоляцию от хост-системы, что может быть неприемлемо для некоторых видов скриптов

Comment: Ну если Docker в Windows и macOS он запускается через виртуальную машину - значит он доступен и для этих платформ. На счет пользователя - тут вообще все что угодно не факт, так что не агрумент. По поводу изоляции - разраб всегда можем смапить в контейнер все что нужно для выполнения скрипта с хоста.

Comment: И всё описанное вами является наслоением сложностей, неприемлемых для простого смертного пользователя, так что лучше уж pyinstaller

Answer (score 0):

либо собрать архив с венвом и проектом, либо под каждое семейство ос собирать бинарник включающий в себя всё необходимое

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Для решении этой задачи необходимо установить на pip (пакет от питона) pyinstaller.
Это можно установить в cmd с такой командой `pip install pyinstaller`. И после загрузки надо зайти в ту папку где находится ваша программа через командную строку и написать `pyinstaller -F main.py`. Подробнее в https://youtu.be/CgCJwDjm_Cw